# Generar sonido al clickar la imagen Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Trabajando con pygame, he creado un programa que genera diversas cosas en pantalla (puntuación, cajita para introducir respuestas...). Entre todo ésto, hay una imagen en medio de la pantalla llamada Clickaudio1.png
Quisiera que la imagen generara un áudio cada vez que el usuario diera click sobre ella, utilizando mixer del mismo pygame. Qué canvios debería hacer para llevar ésto a cabo?

```
import pygame
from InputBox import InputBox

pygame.init()
#Variables
yousayrun = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pointz = 0
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')

def main():
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))
    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))

    #Aquí se genera la imagen 
    imageaudio1 = pygame.image.load("ClickAudio1.png").convert()
    surface.blit(imageaudio1,(190,70))

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
    punts = font.render("Puntuació: " + str(pointz), True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(punts, (350, 30))
    titolsuma3 = font.render("SUMA (3)", True, (0, 0, 0))
    surface.blit(titolsuma3, (10, 20))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
    input_box.draw(surface)
    pygame.display.flip()

input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)

#Main Loop
while yousayrun:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            yousayrun = False
        else:
            main()
            result = input_box.handle_event(event)
            if result != None:
                if int(result) == int(5):
                    pointz = pointz + 5

                input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Aunque no es necesario, la InputBox importada se puede encontrar aquí por si la queréis hechar un ojo:  https://github.com/Maskedllama/InputBox/blob/main/InputBox.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reproducir un sonido tienes primero que cargarlo usando el mixer:
`sonido = pygame.mixer('directorio_del_sonido.ogg')`

Luego tienes que hacer un trigger en el momento que detectas el click. El click es un evento `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. Te dejo el código abajo con algunas recomendaciones.

==========

No relacionado a tu pregunta, tu código no está estructurado correctamente. La función `main()` que llamas dentro del bucle de eventos hace mucho más de lo que debería hacer (define variables que deben estar fuera del bucle de eventos, llama `pygame.init()` en cada vuelta del bucle, etc. Te recomendaría revisarla. A vuelo de pájaro, creo que algo así funcionaría un poco mejor (incluye el sonido):

```
import pygame
from InputBox import InputBox

pygame.init()
#Variables
yousayrun = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pointz = 0
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')

# Esto se puede hacer una sola vez, o puedes envolverlo en una función
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))
imageaudio1 = pygame.image.load("ClickAudio1.png").convert()
# esto lo vas a necesitar para detectar el click
image_position = (190,70)
image_size = imageaudio1.get_rect().size 

font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)
sonido = pygame.mixer('tu_sonido.ogg')

def main():

    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))

    #Aquí se genera la imagen 
    surface.blit(imageaudio1, image_position)

    punts = font.render("Puntuació: " + str(pointz), True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(punts, (350, 30))
    titolsuma3 = font.render("SUMA (3)", True, (0, 0, 0))
    surface.blit(titolsuma3, (10, 20))
    
    input_box.draw(surface)
    pygame.display.flip()


#Main Loop
while yousayrun:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            yousayrun = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # encuentras la posición del click
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # revisas si el click fue en la imágen
            if image_position[0] < click[0] < image_position[0] + image_size[0] and image_position[1] < click[1] < image_position[1] + image_size[1]:
                sonido.play()
                
        main()
        result = input_box.handle_event(event)
        if result != None:
            if int(result) == int(5):
                pointz = pointz + 5
        pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```